# WPF: Button mnemonic does not work if placing the button in a toolbar

Tags: wpf, button, toolbar

If I place a `Button` within a `ToolBar` in WPF:

```
<ToolBar FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"  Grid.Row="1" Name="tools"
         DataContext="{Binding Path=WeekNavigator}">
    <Button Content="_>" Command="{Binding Path=CommandNavigateToNextWeek}"/>
</ToolBar>
```

The text of the button displays "_>" instead of just ">" and the mnemonic doesn't work. If I move the `Button` outside of the `ToolBar` it works as expected.

**How can I get the button to behave the same way inside a toolbar (with regards to mnemonics) as outside of one?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button>
        <AccessText>_></AccessText>
    </Button>
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: perfect! i was hoping the _ to work with the content attribute of a button! xaml always surprises me while learning!