# Enabling mnemonics in button

Tags: wpf, xaml, mnemonics

I read that in order to enable mnemonics, I have to turn on RecognizesAccessKey on ContentPresenter.
When I tried this code, I saw only text without button.

```
<Button x:Name="OkButton" Content="_OK" Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Probably there's a way to change it without deleting button's default template?

Answer (score 5):

[**This question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186738/wpf-button-mnemonic-does-not-work-if-placing-the-button-in-a-toolbar) provides the answer, altough it's not exactly the same question. Here's how the mnemonic is set and working:

```
<Button>
    <AccessText>_Button</AccessText>
</Button>
```

Like in WinForms this is done by adding a `_` before the character to be the mnemonic key.